# Getting error while converting DynamicFrame to a Spark DataFrame using toDF

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, aws-glue

I stated using AWS Glue to read data using data catalog and `GlueContext` and transform as per requirement.

```
val spark: SparkContext = new SparkContext()
val glueContext: GlueContext = new GlueContext(spark)
val sparkSession = glueContext.getSparkSession
// Data Catalog: database and table name
val dbName = "abcdb"
val tblName = "xyzdt_2017_12_05"

// S3 location for output
val outputDir = "s3://output/directory/abc"

// Read data into a DynamicFrame using the Data Catalog metadata
val stGBDyf = glueContext.getCatalogSource(database = dbName, tableName = tblName).getDynamicFrame()
val revisedDF = stGBDyf.toDf() // This line getting error
```

While executing above code I got following error,

> Error : Syntax Error:  error: value toDf is not a member of
>   com.amazonaws.services.glue.DynamicFrame val revisedDF =
>   stGBDyf.toDf() one error found.

I followed [this](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-samples/blob/master/examples/ResolveChoice.scala) example to convert `DynamicFrame` to Spark `dataFrame`. 
Please suggest what will be the best way to resolve this problem

Comment: Hey this is not related but have you tried to read a database directly without crawling it via JDBC? If yes please share a sample code

Answer (score 1):

There's a typo. It should work fine with capital F in toDF:

```
val revisedDF = stGBDyf.toDF()
```

Comment: How do we convert Dataframe to Dynamic Frame in Scala?

Comment: @RudreshAjgaonkar You need to do a `val revisedDynamicFrame = DynamicFrame(revisedDF, glueContext)` (and `import com.amazonaws.services.glue.{DynamicRecord, GlueContext, DynamicFrame}`)